# blank cell checking to avoid null pointer exception

Tags: java, excel

My excel sheet is as follows:

```
Property_id Property_Name                               
3             Hilton                                
Season_start_date   Season_end_date MSG Sun Mon Tues Wed Thurs Fri Sat
9/16/1999            9/16/1999      fxb 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
9/16/1999            9/16/1999      fb  100 100 100 100 100 100 100
9/16/1999            9/16/1999      tfg 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

I had used following code to detect it:

```
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                // Check the cell type and format accordingly

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                     throw new IOException("Cell empty "+cell.getColumnIndex() + cell.getRowIndex()); 

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                    this.propertyId = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    this.propertyName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
            ExcelToDatabase data = new ExcelToDatabase();
            if (data.existingId(propertyId) == 0){
                data.propertyDetails(propertyId, propertyName);
                data.createTable(propertyName);
            }
```

However this code is giving blank cell even for the cell next to property_name. Can u please tell me what should i use to throw exception when blank cell is encountered.

I had also tried :

```
 if (cell == null)
    {
       throw new IOException("blank cell ");  

    }
```

But this does not work.. No exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you wanted to throw exception whenever you encountered blank cell. I guess your problem might be solved if you ignored blank cells.

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                this.propertyId = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                this.propertyName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            default;
                break;

            }
```

Comment: After throwing an exception u cannot write anything like break.. Default is also giving the same problem that unwanted cells are declared as blank

Comment: I didn't understand why you wanted to throw exception for blank cells.

Comment: I want to check if the user has bymistake left a cell blank in my table

Comment: what's wrong with the blank cell next to property_name?